# InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32] vs. [8] - Keras Transfer Learning

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I am trying to perform transfer learning using Mobilenet
Here is my code

```
from keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet
import keras.backend as K

x_train_final=preprocess_input(x_train)
x_test_final=preprocess_input(x_test)
pretrained_weights='imagenet'

#2
mobile=MobileNet(weights=pretrained_weights,include_top=False,input_shape=(416,416,3))
x=mobile.output
x=keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x=keras.layers.Dense(512)(x)
x=keras.layers.Activation("relu")(x)
x=keras.layers.Dense(256)(x)
x=keras.layers.Activation("sigmoid")(x)
x=keras.layers.Dense(8)(x)
output=x
model=keras.models.Model(inputs=mobile.input,outputs=output)

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    loss = K.square(y_pred - y_true)  # (batch_size, 8)
    # summing both loss values along batch dimension
    loss = K.sum(loss, axis=0)        # (batch_size,)

    return loss

model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.002), 
          loss = custom_loss,
          metrics = ['accuracy', 'mse'])

model.fit(x_train_final, y_train, epochs = 100)
```

But I am encountering an error.

```
Epoch 1/100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-55c4376c8a25> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(x_train_final, y_train, epochs = 100)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [32] vs. [8]
     [[node gradients_4/loss_4/dense_18_loss/custom_loss/weighted_loss/mul_grad/Mul_1 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_111168]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

My Train dataset shape is (3066, 416, 416, 3)

Test dataset shape is (100, 416, 416, 3)

I can't figure out the error.

Comment: What is the shape of x_train_final and y_train?

Comment: x_train_final - (3066, 416, 416, 3)
            
y_train - (3066, 8)

Comment: in your custom loss function print the tensors y_pred and y_true before calculating the loss and check if they have same shape and same dtype

Comment: You are loading pretrained weights. But for you image size of 416*416 image, no pretrained shape exist in keras. So, either you should train your model to generate weights, or change the size of your image. The pretrained weights are for image size of 128*128, 160*160, 192*192 and 224*224. Maybe this would solve

Comment: @devSpartan Changing the loss function helped, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and found that there was issue with my pooling layer. It was giving out incorrect output. Changing maxpool2d to globalaevaragepool solved the issue. If you want to stick to maxpool, then change it's output shape.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this , anyway i got the same error message

- tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name,op_name,tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  - - **Incompatible shapes: [8,10] vs. [8,6]** [[node categorical_crossentropy/mul ....

> **Understanding**
>
> - IT is error of **output neural layer shape** not the input to the model.
>   i.e error shows the dimension of the output neural n/w layer.
> - **i.e** : **[what is should be] vs [what the problematic dimension found]**

> **Problem in my case**
>
> 1. in my case - i modified old code :
>
>    - classes list defined : 10         - correct
>    - output_layer = Dense(**units=6**) - this was the problem
>      **Answer :**
> 2. **correction** : output_layer = Dense(**units=10**) as my classes length is 10